# Testing of CAPM

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, interpretation, finance

I'm so confused regarding the test of CAPM with its hypothesis.

So we have these null hypothesis, right?
H0: α = 0, β ≠ 0

If the estimates of intercept a is something 0.4 and t-stat is something insignificant i.e. 1.2, the CAPM holds and it points out that the intercept a = 0, right?. But beta that measures the market risk in my case confuses me more. What if the t-stat of the beta is also insignificant? We would be happy, since we can't reject the null that beta is more than 0. The CAPM holds in such cases? Is it all correct?

Answer (score 0):

If $\hat\alpha=0.4$ with a corresponding $t=1.2$, you cannot reject $H_0\colon \alpha=0$ at the usual significance levels of 5% or 1%. Thus you do not reject the CAPM. (Your interpretation is fine.)

If $\hat\beta=?$ with a corresponding $t=?$ that is close enough to zero, you cannot reject $H_0\colon \beta=0$ at the usual significance levels of 5% or 1%. However, the CAPM says that $\beta\neq 0$, so you would actually want to reject $H_0\colon \beta=0$ if you were rooting for the CAPM. (Your interpretation is not fine.)

Failing to reject $H_0$ indicates that either you do not have enough power (the sample is too small) or the systematic risk (the explanatory variable) is actually irrelevant for explaining the expected value of return on an individual security (the dependent variable). Or perhaps some of the model's or estimation method's assumptions are violated, e.g. the systematic risk has been measured with error (which is quite probable), so we cannot fully trust the result.

Note also that we could try to formulate the null hypothesis as $H_0\colon \beta\neq 0$ but it would be very inconvenient to test it, so we typically avoid such null hypotheses.

Comment: Very good answer Richard. Thank you. So my mistake is that I formulate incorrectly the null hypothesis of beta, right? So it should be H0:β=0 instead of H0:β≠0

Comment: @user375904, the model says $H\colon \beta\neq 0$ but this is hard to test, so you formulate the opposite ($H_0\colon \beta=0$) and try to beat it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

**Background** The CAPM is a one-period model that states that each asset's expected return is positively linearly related to that asset's beta risk. The intercept term is the risk free rate and the coefficient on beta risk is the market risk premium. The market risk premium is the expected return on the market (all assets including stocks, property and bonds) minus the risk free rate. Tests of the model using data over multiple time periods must necessarily involve many compromises.

Nevertheless, there have been many studies since the 1990's that show the CAPM failing badly. Hence the rise of factor models such as the Fama-French three-factor model. See the references in https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2224400 for examples.

Turning to the specifics of your question, unfortunately you have not specified the regression equation you are estimating and the data used. Is it a time series study for a single asset or is it a cross-sectional study? I assume it has stock *excess* returns as the dependent variable. In this case, it is quite common to observe an insignificant coefficient on beta risk because expected stock returns are often found not to be significantly positively related to beta risk.